# JMockit - Throwable is not mockable

Tags: java, testng, java-11, jmockit

I upgraded `org.jmockit:jmockit:1.31 -> org.jmockit:jmockit:1.34` and I'm getting the following error when trying to mock an exception: `Class java.lang.Throwable is not mockable`

What changes were made in Jmockit to no longer make mocking throwable exceptions possible?

```
Java 11
JMockit 1.34
Testng 6.9.10
```

**Test**

```
@Test
public void HttpStatusWhenFailure(@Injectable CustomResponseException e) throws CustomException {
     new Expectations() {{ 
        ProxyManager.rrun((String) any); result = e;
        e.getHttpStatus(); result = 500;
      }};
            
      Response response = resource.run(YearMonth.now().toString());
            
      assertEquals(response.getStatus(), 500);
}
```

**CustomException**

```
@ApplicationException
public class CustomException extends Exception {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 100L;

    protected int httpStatus;

    public CustomException(int httpStatus) {
        super();
        this.httpStatus = httpStatus;
    }

    public CustomException(int httpStatus, String message) {
        super(message);
        this.httpStatus = httpStatus;
    }

    public CustomException(int httpStatus, String message, Throwable cause) {
        super(message, cause);
        this.httpStatus = httpStatus;
    }

    public CustomException(int httpStatus, Throwable cause) {
        super(cause);
        this.httpStatus = httpStatus;
    }

    public int getHttpStatus() {
        return httpStatus;
    }
}
```

Comment: Have the same problem, have you solved this problem?

Answer (score 0):

Using a mock Exception is a bit of overkill here.  This test should work (using a real exception)

```
@Test
public void HttpStatusWhenFailure() throws CustomException {

 new Expectations() {{ 
    ProxyManager.rrun((String) any); result = new CustomResponseException(500, "msg");
  }};
        
  Response response = resource.run(YearMonth.now().toString());
        
  assertEquals(response.getStatus(), 500);
}
```

This test would be treated as if rrun(..) caused the CustomResponseException to be thrown (I believe your intent).  If instead, you want it to act as if it returned an exception (peculiar), there are ways to do that which you can find in other SO posts.

Comment: Unfortunately there are cases where the throwable does not have public constructors, so you can't create one yourself.

Comment: But that's a totally different problem demanding a different solution.  Specifically, you would just (in test code) create a "MyCustomException extends CustomException" with public ctor and then tap it into your test as above (assuming constructors are protected).  Even better - "treat tests as the first consumer of your API" - since your test needed a public ctor, likely your other consumers do too, so expose it (if it's under your control)

Comment: It's not my API, it's not under my control, and constructor is private, not protected. A major use case of any mocking framework is to deal with things in 3rd party libraries that you can't control. So I want to simulate a case where a 3rd party library throws a custom exception (in this case a networking condition that is not really replicable in unit tests) but I can't because jmockit is unnecessarily opinionated. Any why? It wasn't necessary to enforce this in 1.31, so why add the restriction?